# Create-React-App: router is marked as required in Link

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, create-react-app

I've got a problem with Link in react router in one component. Once I try to use Link, the console shows this error: Failed context type: The context `router` is marked as required in `Link`, but its value is `undefined`. I've seen all similar threads about this problem here, but there's no solution to this exact issue. I'm using all the latest versions of all frameworks and componets (just downloaded everything a couple of days ago), so it's definitely not about upgrading anything.

The structure is like this: 
index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import About from './components/About';
import Posting from './components/Posting';
import Groups from './components/Groups';


ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
ReactDOM.render(
    <Router>
        <div>
            <Route exact path='/' component={About} />
            <Route path='/post' component={Posting} />
            <Route path='/groups' component={Groups} />
        </div>
    </Router>,
    document.getElementById('content')
);
registerServiceWorker();
```

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import SideMenuUserInfo from './components/sidemenu/SideMenuUserInfo';
import SideMenu from './components/sidemenu/SideMenu';
import SideMenuFooter from "./components/sidemenu/SideMenuFooter";
import TopNav from "./components/topnav/TopNav";

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <div  className="main_container">
                <div className="col-md-3 left_col">
                    <div className="left_col scroll-view">
                        <div className="navbar nav_title" style={{border: 0}}>
                            <a href="index.html" className="site_title"><i className="fa fa-paw"></i> <span>Logo here</span></a>
                        </div>
                        <div className="clearfix"></div>
                        <SideMenuUserInfo />
                        <br />
                        <SideMenu />
                        <SideMenuFooter />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <TopNav />
                <div id="content" className="right_col" role="main">

                </div>
                <footer>
                    <div className="pull-right">
                       Footer text here
                    </div>
                    <div className="clearfix"></div>
                </footer>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default App;
```

SideMenuUnfoldLink.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

class SideMenuUnfoldLink extends Component {

    render() {

        return(
            <li>
                <a>
                    <i className={this.props.faClass}></i>{this.props.text}<span className="fa fa-chevron-down"></span>
                </a>
                <ul className="nav child_menu">
                    <li><Link to="/">Home</Link></li> <<<<-- THE PROBLEM IS HERE
                </ul>
            </li>
        );
    };
}
export default SideMenuUnfoldLink;
```

And About.js (as a working example of Link)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

class About extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <div>
          <h2>Это About</h2>
          <ul>
            <li><Link to="/groups">Groups</Link></li>
            <li><Link to="/">Main</Link></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
    );
  }
}
export default About;
```

The Link works with the About component like a charm. The error starts to pop up once I use Link in my SideMenuUnfoldLink component.
I suppose the Router is just not initialized by the moment SideMenuUnfoldLink wants to use Link. But how can I go about it?

Answer (score 0):

I've just found the solution. It is to wrap the router around the entire 
application to make it available to all components like this:

```
render() {
        return(
            <Router>
                <div  className="main_container">
                    <div className="col-md-3 left_col">
                        <div className="left_col scroll-view">
                            <div className="navbar nav_title" style={{border: 0}}>
                                <a href="index.html" className="site_title"><i className="fa fa-paw"></i> <span>Logo here</span></a>
                            </div>
                            <div className="clearfix"></div>
                            <SideMenuUserInfo />
                            <br />
                            <SideMenu />
                            <SideMenuFooter />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <TopNav />
                    <div id="content" className="right_col" role="main">

                    </div>
                    <footer>
                        <div className="pull-right">
                           Footer text here
                        </div>
                        <div className="clearfix"></div>
                    </footer>
                </div>
            </Router>
        );
    }
```

And of course removing this part:

```
    ReactDOM.render(
    <Router>
        <div>
            <Route exact path='/' component={About} />
            <Route path='/post' component={Posting} />
            <Route path='/groups' component={Groups} />
        </div>
    </Router>,
    document.getElementById('content')
);
```

Here's a more detailed explanation https://reacttraining.com/react-router/
Lots of thanks to the author of that video :)